# Why will VBScript service only work when a user is logged in?

Tags: c#, vbscript

We execute a script from a webservice that does some actions in VBScript. This script runs from the command line without an error. When we run this script from a service with ProcessStartInfo it does not execute when the user the process is running in is not logged in. We get this error: CScript Error: Loading your settings failed. (Access is denied. ) Though, when the user that executes the service is logged in via remote desktop, the service is running successfully. What could cause this and how could we solve this?

Comment: Have you [searched](http://serverfault.com/questions/230219/vbscript-wont-run-for-domain-user-on-windows-server-2008-r2) for the error?

Comment: I searched on stackoverflow.... Ill give that link a look.

Comment: We did all those actions, but the tip of running process monitor was a good one. We give that a trie.

Comment: We ran process monitor, but I don't see registry access...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What user identity is the VBScript being run under when you get the "Access is denied" message? I'll bet it's `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`, which might explain it.

When you run anything when logged-in by cmd or double-clicking in Explorer then the process runs under the user identity (security context) of the current user. When you're running it outside of a local console session (such as a service session) then it usually runs under the user identity of the parent service process.

By "service" are you referring to a Windows Service (what you see in Services.msc) or your web-service? If it's a web-service then it's run under the user identity of the current IIS Application Pool.

Try running "whoami" (it's a command-line program) from your web-service script and have it redirect the console output to a file. That will tell you the current user identity you're using.

Comment: We did the whoami trick and it was the correct user. After this we tried a reboot and now it is working.